# transformation: Integration to summation

Tags: integration, summation

Good day! I'm studying right now some transformation and I encountered the following equation:

$$(2\pi)^{-n/2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty\cdots\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} \|a\|^2\right)\cdot\cos\left[\varepsilon f(t)\right]\,da_0\cdots da_n = \exp-\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^2 \sum_0^n t^{2k}$$

where $n$ is the degree of a polynomial and $a$ is the coefficients of the polynomial... my question is that..is there a way by any means that a certain series of integration can be converted to summation?... if there is, what method should I consider?